# Access objects globally in templates in Django 1.6

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want a menu on all my pages in Django 1.6.

In the menu I also want to include some objects from my database. I know I can make extend ListView and get the objects, and I know I can set variables in `get_context_data`, but how can I make the objects available on ALL my pages. I think it would be stupid to set the context_data in every single view.

The result of my menu should be something like:

```
Home
Users
    User 1
    User 2
    User 3
Help
Questions
    Question 1
    Question 2
    Question 3
About
```

What would be a good way to do it? Middlewares? Template tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a custom [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS):

You should write a function like this:

```
#file: my_context_processors.py

def menu_data(request):

    return {
            'menu': calculate_menu( request ),  #<-- menu is appended 
                                                #    to your context
                                                #    for all templates
             }
```

Where `calculate_menu` returns an object with menu items and subitems ( dictionary ? ) Remember than you have `path`, `user` and other information into `request`.

Then include your custom processor on app settings template context processors:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    #"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.core.context_processors.csrf",
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'my_app.my_context_processors.menu_data',   #<---- here
    )
```

At this time, `menu` object is available on all your templates.

Do not panic about terms, it is not difficult and this is the right way.

Comment: Thank you! Can I access the url parameters within my custom context processor?

Comment: I can get the full path, but I don't know how to get the URL parameters specified in urls.py.

Comment: Look for [httpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) combined with [ResolverMatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects), that is: [HttpRequest.resolver_match](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match). Post a new question if need help about this topics.